# Weird thing about python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i've got some code:

```
self.nextY = int(self.y + self.aY * 0,7071 - (9.98 * 0.1 * 0.1)/2)
```

And here is traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CrazyDude\workspace\flappy-bird-bot\src\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    bird.get_position(image)
  File "C:\Users\CrazyDude\workspace\flappy-bird-bot\src\flappy.py", line 31, in get_position
    self.nextY = int(self.y + self.aY * 0,7071 - (9.98 * 0.1 * 0.1)/2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

How could it expect for int if i'm changing variable to int?

Comment: What's with the comma `,` in `0,7071`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is passing two arguments to the `int` function. (the second argument is treated as `base` if there's two arguments, it should be integer.)

```
>>> int('10', 2.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
>>> int('10', 2)
2
```

Maybe you mean `0.7071` instead of `0,7071`?

Comment: Damn. Thanks, forgot to change number format after notepad copying. Thanks again!